# Android Studio - No puedo controlar la cantidad de Tooltips

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tooltip

**Descripción:**

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la cual le doy mucho uso a **Tooltip** de la librería:

```
implementation 'com.github.vihtarb:tooltip:0.1.9'
```

Lo uso tantas veces que decidí pasar la creación de estos tooltips a una clase padre. Es decir, que cada vez que hago uso de estos, llamo a una clase a la cual le paso los parámetros para activar el tooltip.

**Problema:**

El problema que me generó haberlos pasado a  esta clase, es que no puedo controlar la cantidad de tooltips mostrados. Lo que quiero decir es que se pueden tocar vistas que hagan aparecer tooltips, y estos siempre van a aparecer, incluso si ya hay otros tooltips activados.

**¿Que quiero?**

Quiero que solamente se active un tooltip por vez. Para que aparezca otro, primero tiene que desaparecer el que ya se está mostrando

**Adjunto el código de la clase padre:**

```
public class retornar_tooltip{

public Tooltip tooltip = null;

padre p = new padre();

public void mostrarTooltip(Context context, View v, int votos){
    //Condición con la cual valido la existencia de otro tooltip (me funcionaba hasta que pasé el código a esta clase)
    if(tooltip != null){
        tooltip.dismiss();
    }
    else if(tooltip == null){
        tooltip = new Tooltip.Builder(v)
                .setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.votado_por) + " " + votos + " " + (context.getResources().getString(R.string.alumnos)).toLowerCase())
                .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"))
                .setGravity(Gravity.TOP)
                .setCornerRadius(8f)
                .setDismissOnClick(true)
                .setArrowHeight(18f)
                .show();

        p.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tooltip.dismiss();
            }
        },3000);
    }
}
}
```

**Adjunto el código JAVA que utilizo para activar los tooltips:**

```
retornar_tooltip rt = new retornar_tooltip();

//TXT CALIFICACION EVENT LISTENER
    txt_calificacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vista) {
            rt.mostrarTooltip(getApplicationContext(),vista,41);
        }
    });
```

Este código hace que solamente pueda activar un tooltip. Al hacerlo aparecer, ya no puedo hacer que aparezcan más, a menos que reinicie la app.

**Aclaración:**

Quiero hacer hincapié en que este mismo código me funcionaba antes de haberlo pasado a la clase padre.

**¿Que puede estar pasando?**

**Gracias por leer!**

Comment: Haciendo debug si entra en el if para que hagas el dismiss?

Comment: Hola Eric y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer y responder. No entendí lo que me quisiste decir. Podrías por favor explicarte mejor?

Comment: Tienes este if if(tooltip != null){. Mi pregunta era si ejecutando en modo debug puedes comprobar que si funciona ese if.

Comment: No lo probé en modo Debug. Lo que si se es que antes de haber pasado el código a esta clase padre, el código (osea el if también) funcionaba perfectamente y hacía lo que yo quería.

Comment: Cabe recalcar que la pregunta tiene un buen formato. Así deberían ser todas las preguntas. Excelente descripción!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: Revísale en modo debug y me comentas.